# Blazor .NET 8 Auto Services with Auth-Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, asp.net-identity

I would like to migrate from my Blazor WASM/ASP .NET Core Web API to the new Blazor .NET 8 Auto. I have now moved all my services from the Web API to the server project.

But now the question is how I can securely access the services in the client and the server project.

I use Identity and want to make sure that only authenticated users can access services.

So the question is. How can I access such a service in a Razor page in the client and on the server and give it the user ID, for example, without it potentially being manipulated?

Or is it the case that I can simply inject my services directly as soon as I have set the [Authorize] attribute? I would then retrieve the current user information via the Auth-State-Provider and give it to my service. But I'm not sure whether this can be done in this way.

I've searched a lot on the subject, but haven't found a good documentary on it. In general, Blazor .NET 8 still confuses me relatively, regarding authentication.

Comment: My first question is "Why do you want to move to Auto?"  Why not "InteractiveWebAssembly"?  I initially considered Auto for an application I'm migrating from 3.1.   After some investigations and testing I dismissed it.  There's this answer I wrote recently - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768044/how-do-i-share-state-to-be-injected-across-components-rendered-in-different-rend/77768838#77768838.  You'll find my commentary on my findings here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/Going-For-Broke.md

Comment: Because I want server and client-side rendering.

Comment: OK, but note "I've searched a lot on the subject, but haven't found a good documentary on it. In general, Blazor .NET 8 still confuses me relatively, regarding authentication." is because I'm pretty sure there isn't any.  Hence my research and commentary.   Good luck in building your application.

Comment: Bruh. I didn't quite understand your point overall. Why did you write to me in a question about Blazor Auto that I should use WASM? That's where I'm coming from....

Answer (score 0):

This is not, strictly, a direct answer to the question as, in my opinion, the question is a bit too broad/open ended for us to try and retro fit authentication into your app. But what I have tried, and would suggest you try, is to create a new app from the built in templates and use that to guide you in fitting in the necessary bits into your own app.

Look at the client side pieces it adds, the services it registers on both the client and the server. Then run it and step through it carefully and watch how it does everything and what happens.

You can use Visual Studio's "new project" or a command line similar to:

```
dotnet new blazor --auth Individual --interactivity Auto --name BlazorAuthDemo --output ./source/blazorauthdemo
```

This way you get to see the Microsoft latest recommended way of doing things. Especially as auth on the new Blazor has changed a lot over the last few months.

And, of course, the official MS docs on the topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0