# Blazor Server Web App .Net 8 Example Repos

Tags: .net, blazor, repo

I have worked with Blazer Server for the past year.  I am starting a new app and I am going to use the new Blazor Server Web App template in .Net 8, that allows both server side and client rendering.

I have played around with the Counter app.  But im still a bit unsure where to put my assets.

I would like to look at a more real life example of this type of app.  To see where it puts its code and assets

Do you know of any public repos that use this new .Net Web App approach.  I would find it helpful to look at this code to understand it better

TIA

Comment: See this answer and the referenced commentary for some further information - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768044/how-do-i-share-state-to-be-injected-across-components-rendered-in-different-rend

Comment: Does this what you want? E.g the EF CORE sample inside the link https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/tree/main/8.0