# how to inject to client blazor service from blazor server

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, blazor, single-page-application

How to make the services in the Blazor Server project repository visible in the Blazor client in the program class.The ITemplates interface and the TemplatesService service are not visible because I cannot add a namespace from Blazor Server. Blazor Client dependencies are added to the Blazor Server project by default. Project .NET8

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
// Register our own injectables
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITemplates, TemplatesService>();
```

I want to inject methods with objects directly defined from the repository in razor components.

Comment: You can run the same services [or interface defined services] as long as they are compatible to both modes of operation.  But you can't share the same instance or state.  See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77768838/13065781

Answer (score 0):

Create a Shared Interface in Client Project or Create a new shared project and refer to the both of the projects and create

```
ITemplates, TemplatesService
```